# C++ function call with type pointer, parameter confusion: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to wrap my head around C++. I'm going to just give you tiny pieces to help illustrate the idea without making things to convoluted. Btw, im only implementing these methods, i cannot change the setup or parameters.

I have a class for a dynamic array data structure that holds objects called stocks:

```
typedef class Stock ArrayType;

class DynamicArray {
    ArrayType** items;
    int numberOfElements;
    ...
}
```

Here's its constructor. I'm supposed to allocate the array and add one item, then set the number of elements.

```
DynamicArray::DynamicArray(ArrayType* const item){
    Stock *items = NULL; // ... i guess? pointers to pointers confuse me
    // now im guessing i need to create a actual stock array and point the above pointer to it
    items = new Stock[1]; // ERROR: incomplete type is not allowed? I've tried several things, and cant get rid of the red squiggles
    this->numberOfElements = 1;
}
```

Comment: Try defining the Stock class before Dynamic array. I ran into a similar error before, and the problem was literally that the compiler didn't have the complete definition of the object at the time.

Comment: I changed the order of the includes, but still no juice. That part of the code my teacher provided anyways, so i'm not supposed to have to touch it.

Comment: In the constructor, change: `Stock *items` to `Stock *items[]`

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot man. I did this: Stock *items[1]; items[0] = item;

Comment: Excellent that it got it to compile, but I don't think that's the goal of your exercise. You allocated an array of `Stock` pointers on the stack, so once the program exits the constructor the result will be garbage-collected. See my answer below for the right way to do it with pointers. I did my best to duplicate your code, so the solution *should* work, and I'll keep watching this question in case you run into any more hurdles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are a few problems. Off the bat, you have to include Stock first. The compiler needs the full definition of `Stock` before it can compile `DynamicArray`, because of memory allocation by my guess.

Secondly, you want the `items` *member-value* to contain the reference to the array created in the constructor. So instead of defining `Stock *items[1]` in the constructor, assign the value of the `new` statement directly to `this->items`; you can ommit `this->` as long as you don't define a variable with the same name in whatever function you're working on.

Finally, you're allocating an *array of pointers*, so you use this syntax: `new ArrayType*[1]`

Additionally, just as a coding-practices point, you shouldn't mix the use of typedefs and their original types in the same source. So I'd recommend you use `ArrayType` throughout or not at all.

Comment: Thanks. That worked: "this->items = new ArrayType*[1]; items[0] = item;". Although I'm not sure i understand the difference between that and this: "ArrayType *items[1]; items[0] = item;".

Comment: Stack versus heap allocation, primarily. Something allocated on the stack is garbage-collected when it falls out of scope. Something allocated on the heap sticks around until explicitly freed. Functionally in this case, you would not be able to resize `items`, because the space for the array is pre-allocated, and you cannot `delete` a stack-allocated variable.